# Save game in Soul Reaver

Tags: soul-reaver

I am probably the only one who did not figure this out but... How do I save the game in Legacy of Kain: Soul Reaver? I found a new portal but when I return to the game I still start from the abyss. And when I approached the first portal nothing happens: I can see the portal that I unlocked but if I try to press A (I am playing it on a PC) nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: From what I recall it saves automatically at certain points. You have to play through to one of these points. Yeah, old school. Plus you always start in the Abyss, and have to run back to where you were.

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing the PC version, and not the emulated PS1 version of the game, you should be able to save in the Escape menu.

- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and select `Save game` option.
- Then select a save slot and enter your save's name.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

you save your game selecting "save game" from the Escape menu.
To load, you go to the first Gate in the abyss, press Action while standing on one of the circles, press Left/Right until you find an unlocked gate you wish to travel to, then walk Forward.
To unlock a new gate, you must first find them the old fashioned way and stand on one of its circles.